# why does my code multiply 2 times instead of one

Tags: python, if-statement, math

My code should verify if a number is even, if it is, it prints the number multiplied by 2, if it isn't, it should print the number multiplied by 3, but just doesn't work.

```
m = int(input())
for i in range(m):
    n = int(input())
    n*=2 if n%2==0 else n*3
    print(n)
```

When i try this input:

```
3
1
2
3
```

It returns:

```
3
4
**27** <- ?
```

Comment: If n is odd, the second to last line reduces to `n *= n*3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
n *= 2 if n % 2 == 0 else n * 3
```

means

```py
n *= (2 if n % 2 == 0 else n * 3)
```

which means

```py
if n % 2 == 0:
    n = n * 2
else:
    n = n * n * 3
```

You meant to write

```py
n *= 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n*=2 if n%2==0 else n*3
```

Operator precedence.

This statement is interpreted as

```
n *= (2 if n%2==0 else n*3)
```

And for input 3, n%2==0 is not true, so the statement becomes

```
n *= 9
```

Which is 27.